# custom hashing of forgot password using cloud code or javascript sdk of parse.com

Tags: parse-platform

I have a custom hash that I apply to passwords so that it matches the legacy .net membership provider hashing. I apply the hash clientside when registering users, but the forgot password link, since it is done by parse without the has, creates an issue.

Can I create a cloud code method or event handler that can capture password reset events so that I can hash it?

I tried creating my own forgot password cloud code function but it seems to not be able set the password since there is no logged in user during the cloud code function request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to manipulate user objects while in Cloud Code, use the Parse.useMasterKey() method to override the normal security settings. Although I can't really recommend trying to manipulate the password yourself of course.